# filter in react with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am applying following filter on a table with the help if useEffect

```
useEffect(()=>{
let updated = data.filter(function(e){
if ((e.country === aaa|| e.country === undefined) && (e.age === bbb|| e.age === undefined)){
  return true
}
})
  setRows(updated)
},[aaa, bbb])
```

it works fine when "Select" for both the filters are selected if one if them is undefined then it does not show any data

Answer (score 0):

I prefer making multiple functions when filtering criteria differs. It's more readable for other developers and easier to modify and maintain.

I don't know about the actual end result since I don't know your exact use case. But this structure of code should give you a hint on how to approach that:

```js
const byCountry = (country) => (item) => {
  return item.country === country || item.country === undefined;
};

const byAge = (age) => (item) => {
  return item.age === age || item.age === undefined;
};

const getUpdated = (data, country, age) => {
  return data
    .filter(byCountry(country))
    .filter(byAge(age));
};


const data = [{
  country: 'Finland',
  age: '42',
}, {
  country: 'Sweden',
  age: '39',
}, {
  country: 'Sweden',
}];



console.log(getUpdated(data, 'Finland', '42'));
console.log(getUpdated(data, 'Sweden', '39'));
```

Comment: Even easier to read if you curry the predicates, so you don't need to `.bind()` them: `byCountry = country => item => { return item.country === country || item.country === undefined; };` and then `.filter(byCountry(country))`

Comment: Wow @VLAZ , that was very good improvement. I even wasn't aware of that until today :). Thanks, I made the changes to original answer